# How to plot a high resolution image in ggplot without saving the file?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a restricted data online which I do not have access to. I can still get the outputs of my codes, but I cannot access any saved files of the outputs. Options like `ggsave` and other ones permit to have high-resolution quality figures, but then I cannot use these as I do not have access to the folders. Is there another way to produce these figures without having to save them? I can have access to the figures that plot in the R interface.

Let's suppose we use this code:

```
plot= ggplot(mtcars, aes(displ, hwy)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth()
```

If we type `plot`, R will display the graph. Is there a way to modify its resolution, length and width? and then to type `plot` and get these modifications?

Comment: Define "the folders"? `ggsave` does not only allow you to write to the same folder of your project, but you could write it for example to your own user environment `C:\Users\youhaveaccessfolder`

Comment: I don't think this will work, i have only access to the plot that shows in the R environment. I do not have access to anything else since i am working only online with this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running remote scripts (e.g. via ssh) that output a svg representation of a plot, you might consider using [repr](https://github.com/IRkernel/repr/).
Here's an example code (hack) that can work in non interactive mode on linux servers:

```
sink(file = "/dev/null") # suppresses all the output
library(ggplot2)
library(repr)
png(filename = "/dev/null") # start an arbitrary device. (it does not really matter)
dev.control("enable") #set this to allow recording from the device
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()

print(g)
p <- recordPlot()     #record it 
dev.off()             #close the device
sink()                #restore the output 
cat(repr_svg(p), width = 7, height = 7))    #print out the svg
```

Save the script to e.g. example_script.R, then run in a terminal

```
cat example_script.R | ssh myuser@myhost Rscript '-' > example.svg
```

This will save the results in the file example.svg
[image: example]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how can i modify the length and resolution of the graph before printing at the end? using which function? I usually use `ggsave`, but not sure here what to use

Comment: You should specify better how are you connecting to the remote server: e.g. ssh, jupyter, RStudio. I was providing an answer (hack) to quickly get an image from an instance of R running remotely via ssh. Moreover, if you use a vector format such as svg or pdf, you don't need to specify resolution as these formats scale to any size. Still you may want to specify image size to get all graphic elements well proportioned.